# Вопрос по передаче указателя из функции на си в c++ builder

Tags: c, c++builder

Есть функция (`getmymass`) которая возвращает указатель на массив. В методе main я делаю так:

```
int *mass;
mass = GETMYMASS();
```

Все элементы передаются если использовать `mass[x]`.
А вот получить размерность массива способом: `sizeof(mass)/sizeof(int)` - не получается.
Возвращает единицу (`4/4`)
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeof(mass)/sizeof(int) возвращает размер указателя и размер для типа int, они совпадают.
Нельзя узнать размер массива в памяти, его надо передавать отдельно.

Comment: Либо в память записывать какой-нибудь разделитель. Тогда можно будет читать по указателю до разделителя.

Comment: а еще проще пользоваться каким-нибудь vector'ом

Answer (score 4):

Массивы в C/C++ никак не хранят размер. Указатель на массив - это лишь указатель на его первый элемент, а операция индексации `arr[i]` обращается к области памяти со смещением `i` от указателя, т.е. эквивалентно записи `*(arr + i)`. Размер необходимо хранить отдельно.

> (Лирическое отступление) Для строковых
> массивов в C принято соглашение -
> добавлять в конец специальный
> элемент-маркер - нульсимвол или
> зеротерминатор, обозначаемый '\0', и
> сами строки называют
> "null/zero-terminated string". Именно
> таким образом любая строковая функция, например strlen(const
> char*), идет от указателя на начало
> по всей строке,  пока не встретит '\0', хотя сам буфер может быть длиннее, чем позиция '\0', которая считается условным концом строки.

В вашем случае, можно передавать указатель на буфер, как выходной аргумент и возвращать его размер.

```
/* C'шная функция */
size_t getMyArray(int **outPtr)
{
    size_t arraySize = 333;
    *outPtr = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int) * arraySize );
    return arraySize;
}

// Использование
int *iPtr = nullptr;
size_t size = getMyArray(&iPtr);

for(size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) 
{
    cout << iPtr[i] << endl;
}

free(iPtr); // Не забываем
```

Comment: да, а если размерность массива мне неизвестна?
я вычислял ее используя цикл, т.е. получается два одинаковых цикла - один определяет длину массива, второй задает значения. 
Как избежать этого?
Можно ли сделать так:

int *mass;
сначала использовать malloc для инициализации нулевого значения
а в цикле добавлять память realloc - ом?

Comment: Посмотрите как пользоваться http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ или если у вас билдер, то TList. И отредактируйте свой вопрос с кодом создания массива, тогда будет понятно что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @Андрей Анфилец
Размерность массива должна быть известна обязательно.

В Си нет многомерных массивов в принципе. Но мы можем две вещи: объявлять указатели произвольной глубины (указатель, указатель на указатель и т.п.) и выделять непрерывную область памяти необходимой длинны (буфер). С помощью этих средств мы можем эмулировать многомерные массивы. Для двумерного частного случая, мы можем делать, например, указатель на массив указателей, каждый из которых указывает на начало своего буфера (строки).

Comment: @Андрей Анфилец

    const int ROWS_N = 3;
    const int COLS_N = 3;
    
    // Массив указателей на строки
    int **arr = new int*[ROWS_N];
    
    // Выделяем память для каждой строки
    for (int i=0; i<ROW_N; ++i)
        arr[i] = new int[COLS_N];
    
    // Использование
    arr[i][j] = ... 
    // то же самое, что и
     *( *( arr+i ) + j) = ...

Для R^3, это уже будет указатель на указатель на указатель, который указывает на "двойной" указатель на массив одиночных указателей. То есть мы одномерные массивы сцепили в двумерный, а теперь двумерные массивы сцепляем в трехмерный.

Comment: @Андрей Анфилец
Вам выше все настойчиво советуют использовать шаблонный класс динамического массива std::vector. По сути, там будет тот же принцип вложенности: vector<int> для одномерного массива, vector<vector<int>> для двумерного массива, и т.п. Но там уже есть метод size(), с помощью которого можно узнать количество элементов вектора (но не размерность).